# git filter-branches not covering remote branches

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I'm trying to filter branches a la this tutorial https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/.

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch $1" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git push --force --all
```

is only filtering the branch master, and not the orgin/ branches. I had to write this script instead:

```
for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/)
do
    git checkout $branch
    git filter-branch --force --index-filter "git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch $1" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
    git push --force --all
done
```

Any ideas how I can get the first command to loop over all references so that I don't have to do the loop myself?

Answer (score 6):

> [`git filter-branch ... --all`] is only filtering the branch master, and not the orgin/ branches ...

That's normal and desirable, because the `origin/` names aren't actually *branch* names at all.  (Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names*, which I think sounds too much like "branch names"—it has the phrase "branch name" right in there after all!—so I have taken to calling them "remote-tracking names" to help distinguish them.)

A remote-tracking name is *your* Git's memory of some *other* Git's branch.  When you use `git filter-branch`, you are telling your Git to copy commits in your repository, making some change(s) just before committing the copies, and then update *your* branch names to point to the new copied—presumably new-and-improved—commits instead of the original (old and lousy?) commits.

Your subsequent `git push --force --all` asks your Git to send, to their Git, all of your branch names and their corresponding commit hash IDs, along with any commits you have that `origin` lacks that are required to make this all work.  Then your Git commands (`--force`) their Git to set *their* branch names the same way yours are, i.e., pointing to the copied, new-and-improved commits.  If they accept this command, your Git will update your remote-tracking names.

In general, what you want to do is find all your remote-tracking names corresponding to *their* branch names:

```
git for-each-ref refs/remotes/origin  # add --format options as appropriate
```

and use these names to make sure that you have *your own* branch names, pointing to the same commit as these remote-tracking names.  The below is not tested, so verify it first.  It also doesn't actually *fail* when things are wrong (because `prog | while ...` makes that too hard), it just prints warnings.

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/remotes/origin |
    while read name; do
        shortname=${name#refs/remotes/}
        localname=${name#refs/remotes/origin/}
        # if we have a branch named $localname, make sure it
        # identifies the same commit as $name.  If not, create
        # one pointing to $name.
        fullname=refs/heads/$localname  # use full name in case of tags etc
        if hash=$(git rev-parse $fullname); then
            if test $hash != $(git rev-parse $name); then
                echo "WARNING: local branch $localname differs from $shortname"
            else
                echo "local branch $localname is good (matches $shortname)"
            fi
        else
            echo "creating local branch $localname to match $shortname"
            # NB: you can add --track here but that is the default anyway
            if ! git branch $localname $name; then
                echo "WARNING: failed to create $localname"
            fi
        fi
    done
```

Now you actually have a branch per remote-tracking branch (plus any of your own branches that don't have remote-tracking names).  *Now* your `--all` on your `filter-branch` will do what you want.

There's another issue, perhaps minor or irrelevant.  Your filter-branch says:

```
... --tag-name-filter cat ...
```

which tells your `git filter-branch` to update any of your tags.  But your final `git push` says `git push --force --all`, and `--all` in `git push` means *push all branches*, not *push all branches and tags*.  If your `git filter-branch` *did* update some tags, you probably should push them as well.

Note that changing tags in public repositories is generally a bad idea, as it's tricky to be sure all other users of those repositories to pick up the new tag values that go with the existing tag names.  If it's appropriate, though, one should go ahead and do it, and just warn all the users *of* that public repository that the tags have changed.